# Strange compile error when overloading operator !=

Tags: c++

I have created my own version of `operator !=` so that I can use `p != NULL` instead of `p->b == 0`.  However, when compiling it (g++ v4.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04), I get the error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te2b.cc
te2b.cc:8:41: error: ‘bool operator!=(strDum*, void*)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct strDum {
    int a;
    int b;
};
bool operator!= (strDum *p, void *unused) {
    return p->b != 0;
}

int main(void) {
    strDum *x = (strDum*) malloc(sizeof(strDum) * 4);
    x[0].a = 10; x[0].b = 20;
    x[1].a = 100; x[1].b = 200;
    x[2].a = 1000; x[2].b = 0;
    strDum *y;
    for (y=x; y!= NULL; y++) {
        printf("%5d %5d\n", y->a, y->b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

By the way, I prefer `p != NULL` to `p->b == 0` because the structure strDum and the criteria may change frequently (`p != NULL` may become `p->c == 0`)

**UPDATE1**

As the declaration `bool operator!= (strDum *p, void *unused)` shows,  p is only going to be compared with "NULL".

Comment: You can't overload the operator for pointer, only for object.

Comment: How would you compare `y` itself to another pointer if you had that overload?

Comment: Well, [fixing your primary syntactical problems](http://ideone.com/mrnNG7), your code seems to end up in undefined behavior.

Comment: Using the `!=` operator seems unintuitive to me in this situation. I suggest you use a member function, say `bool strDum::isZero() const` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare an operator overloaded function that takes pointers as arguments.
Consider doing this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

struct strDum {
    int a;
    int b;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator!= (strDum const& p, T const& number) {
    return p.b != number;
}

//may want to include other operators like == as well

int main(void) {

    strDum *test = new strDum;
    if (*test != 0){
        // data member did not equal zero ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You can not declare an operator which only takes pointers as arguments. From the standard:

> **13.5.6 Overloaded operators [over.oper]**
>
> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function that **has at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration.** It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or
>   number of operands of operators. The meaning of the operators
>   = , (unary) & , and , (comma), predefined for each type, can be changed for specific class and enumeration types by defining operator
>   functions that implement these operators. Operator functions are
>   inherited in the same manner as other base class functions.

Comment: Thanks @Beta Carotin for pointing it out, I realized it after posted the question :-)